# Какая разница между SSR и CSR?

Tags: reactjs, nextjs

Объясните пожалуйста доступным языком какая разница между этими двумя понятиями.

То есть **ReactJS** тоже получает дату через **REST** и рендерит на странице и **NextJS** тоже самое.Так какое же между ними разница?

Чем отличаются эти понятия объясните  `SSR` и `CSR`?

Когда можно использовать **Next** а когда сам **React**?

Буду рад если будет ссылки на доп. ресурсы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSR - это client side rendering , главное его проблемой это то что страницы не индексируются например google или yandex не могут индексировать и даже fb share не работает.

SSR - это server side rendering, здесь уже все наоборот.

Если нужно углубленное понятие:
https://techrocks.ru/2019/02/24/server-side-and-client-side-rendering/

Comment: Почему это не индексируется есть же React helmet для SEO

Comment: присоединюсь к вопросу. т.к. как минимум есть жеж `#!` (hash bang).